# Different users select same key in java hashmap at same time --- will it be thread safe?

Tags: java, collections

I have a function working in java such that HashMap has a store of key as String and value as ArrayList. So my quetion is when different user login at the same time and they try to access the webapplication and will selecet the same key , than in that case hashmap need to be synchronized ?

like ..When User1 will login the vlaue in hashmap will store behind the scene such as 
map.put(A, List1)
map.put(B, List2)

When User2 will login the vlaue in hashmap will store behind the scene such as 
map.put(A, List3)
map.put(C, List4)

so now if both user will login at the same time and key is same but (List values are always different ) than this hashmap need to be synchronized ??.

Comment: It says clearly in the documentation for the HashMap class, that it is not thread safe.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether you're using the same key, `HashMap` simply isn't thread safe for any writing:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.)

Even if there are different keys involved, two operations at the same time could both trigger internal map expansion, leading to problems. (Or even if there's one write operation and one read operation, if the write operation adds or removes a key, that could throw off the read operation.)

Options:

- Use a synchronized collection (e.g. [`Collections.synchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-))
- Use a concurrent collection (e.g. [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html))
- Synchronize all access yourself

EDIT: If in fact it turns out you *don't* have multiple threads concurrently modifying the map (because you have one map per user) then most of the issue goes away... although if there could still be multiple threads accessing the map (just not at the same time) I'd be tempted to use a concurrent map *anyway* to avoid issues of stale reads etc.

Comment: but i think synchronized collection should be used when resources are shared . So if i have always different key values for different users ..still it need to be synchronized ?

Comment: @gSingh: Your *map* is the shared resource. As I said, the fact that they're different keys doesn't make it safe. If all the keys were allocated in the map before you started, then there wouldn't be any structural modification and you might be okay... but I would just use a `ConcurrentHashMap` probably.

Comment: @gSingh Your best option is probably to not use a Map at all, and store what needs to be stored in a database. If you want in-memory state bound to a specific user, use the HttpSession. That's what it's for.

Comment: @jon thanks for clearing this...please clear this also ....actually as soon user logging in i am storing all the values for that user in Map and than putting that map in session and in further pages user will be modifying that map. So even if i put that map in session for the user and in the mean time another user login --in this case also i need to use ConcurrentHashMap  ?

Comment: @gSingh: Yes. Because you're still using multiple threads and at least one of those threads may be making a structural change. See the documentation I quoted early in my answer.

Comment: @gSingh: every user will have its own session, and thus its own map. Modifications done by one user won't affect the map of another user. A single user can still send concurrent requests, handled by concurrent threads, accessing the user's map, though. So you still need synchronization. But I repeat: use your database. Be as stateless as possible.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your response !! one query---  you said "A single user can still send concurrent requests" --how this is possible , can you please explain ? one user will be logging in once only right and as per you will have its own session and thus its own map.

Comment: I wanted to be sure before i convert my hashmap to concurrenthashmap in my code....and after JBNizet last comment i think i need not to do so. Since i am using the session and thus the user own map. but this comment create a doubt " "A single user can still send concurrent requests" --i dont think in my case single user is sending the concurrent request ...

Comment: @gSingh: Ah, so you *don't* have one map that multiple threads will be using? Your question strongly suggests that you are. If you only have a single map per user, then the whole premise of the question seems to go away...

Comment: @JonSkeet i would really appreciate if you can help me understand more---- My scenerio is that worldwide users will login and as soon as they login the map values will get store according to his/her access/or groups he belonged to. so, is this a multiple thread scenerio ?? I wanted to tell you surely that i have not done any custom threading coding in my app. Please help me explain this..Does my scenerio look like multiple threading ?

Comment: @gSingh: You talk about "the map" - do you mean a *single* map, or one map per user? It's vital that you make that distinction.

Comment: i think it is single map in my java....Map map = new HashMap(); map.put(key, values) --in for loop . The key values are coming from webservice on the basis of user who logged in. hope this answer ur question ....

Comment: @gSingh: Well that's not the same as what you said to JB Nizet about "putting that map in session" - if it's one map per session, then that's *not* just a single map. I think you really need to start off by working out how your code works at all, before you worry about the threading part.

Comment: @JonSkeet   as i said...first i am creating the Map and storing the values according to the user and than putting that map in the session so that i can retirve that map again in further java classes while user is till in the session and can modify that map......hope this explain what i am doing ....

Comment: @gSingh: Not really. You need to work through your code yourself and work out whether you've *really* got one map per user, or one map across the whole system. I *suspect* you've got one map per user, but it's unclear and you really, really need to understand this for yourself.

Comment: @JonSkeet  okay...i agreed and i dig into this more. so here is my quest. again ----In my application, I create new hashmap and save it in session in first servlet and use it in the next servlet. so, is this map need to be synchronized ? What will happen iF any other user logged in between ? I am thinking that for new user that will be a completely new map since i am creating new object of map and putting that in session for that user always . I hope i am clear this time......

Comment: @gSingh: That sounds like a question you should ask in a new post, with more details - particularly around how you're performing session handling in general. It's not really about the thread safety of maps any more.

Comment: @JonSkeet okay Thanks Jon...for ur answers and clearing my doubts !! I will put this in a new post......Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. But as soon as multiple threads access a non-thread-safe collections, and at least one of them writes to the collection, then you need proper synchronization, and **all** the accesses to the map must be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jon Skeet
 "if there are different keys involved, two operations at the same time could both trigger internal map expansion, leading to problems"

But there can be specific scenario as "*HashMap is filled only at the start of application with data  like database connection parameters etc. and later we only fetch data from it*" then Select operation for every thread would  return same value.

In all the other scenarios as mentioned by Jon Skeet you have below options 
   1) Use a synchronized collection (e.g. Collections.synchronizedMap)
   2) Use a concurrent collection (e.g. ConcurrentHashMap)
   3)Synchronize all access yourself

Comment: @shirsih Thanks ! i will use these options one more doubt..when i will use say ConcurrentHashMap and store List values in it than do those List values also need to be synchronized ? or ConcurrentHashMap will take care of that ?

Comment: In case of ConcurrentHashMap please refer to    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html . As far as I understand concurrentHashMap have synchronized update Operations on HashMap but the values in that Map can be still accessed by many thread.Here as you are using List I think you should synchronize the list also .